# UV map not working properly

Tags: uv

So I have a UV map of a character. I want to color the eyes of the character.
For that, I go export the UV map from Blender, apply color on it via Photoshop then import the colored UV map into Blender again (texture node). Everything works fine, except when I color the eyes: the map doesn't get proprely applied on the model:
[image]

[image]

Now, the weird part is that someone else managed to properly color the eyes using the same UV map! But he was using Substance painter.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my model in UV editing mode:
[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I can't see any UVs in your screenshots, so I can't even tell if the colors are in the correct positions to color your model where they should. Because if they are not, well that's the problem, the colors need to be in the right place.

Comment: Another idea, are you even using a UV map at all for positioning the texture on the model? Because you're texture looks like the eye and pupil are separated from each other, but on the model it looks like the texture is simply put on there as if it was all one piece. Do you have a _Texture Coordinate_ node plugged into the _Vector_ of the _Image Texture_ node and maybe use a different output than _UV_ - maybe _Object_ or _Generated_ or something like that?

Comment: Hi @GordonBrinkmann thank you for your help! I added a screenshot of my model in UV editing mode on my post. Is it what you needed?

Comment: I tried what you said with the nodes: added a texture coordinate, plugged (generated) to the texture node (vector) but I still don't get a correct application of the color on the eyes.

Comment: Upload the file and people can figure this issue out quickly.  Otherwise, it's just a guessing game.

Comment: @Rose I didn't tell you to **try** to plug _Generated_ into the vector... I was asking **if** you have a _Texture Coordinate_ node and maybe use something different than _UV_, for example _Object_ or _Generated_ (which would cause **incorrect** placing). In your screenshot there are still no UVs visible, just black areas (UVs are the representation of the unwrapped faces, they should look like a mesh just in 2D). As Nathan said, better upload the file or it's all a guessing game.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann here is a link to the file: https://we.tl/t-al3hSIIyKc

Comment: @Rose I thought you would have a Blender file with a texture already attached to it. If I have to build it myself I know I'm doing it correctly. But I guess I already found some possible error. The OBJ file you uploaded comes with a UV map that seems to fit the image texture (maybe not exactly, hard to tell since you didn't include it), where the two eyes are placed next to each other. But in your screenshot of the UVs the one on the right is missing and it's moved farther right beyond the pink area.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann here is a link with textures attached https://we.tl/t-VOrB1F8Sqg